# tenses with the expression it.... two years since

Tags: past-tense

> She invited me to dinner. But it _____ two years since I _____ to her house. So I lost my way.

The answers were "was" and "had gone".

Could they be "had been" and "went"?

Comment: Absolutely! The combination of "had" and "gone" doesn't make sense!

Comment: Ah I misread your question. I read "answer was"..."had" and "gone". Well...even if I prefer the combination of "had been" + "went", I think the combination "was" + "had gone" would be Okay.

Comment: No I was wrong. It would be completely alright!